# JQuery AJAX unable to locate URL / Pass Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script passing username and password value to server script (php) for form validation and it works fine when hosted locally but when i recently moved it online, it seems ajax is unable to find the url and returns with [object][object].

jquery code:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sitename/s_logincheck.php',
    data: {UserName:UID, Password:PWD},
    cache: false,
    error: function(data) { alert(data); }
    success: function(data) { if(data==0) { //redirect to home page }}
});
```

Also, my server side statement to retrieve post values:

```
$FormUserName = strtolower($connectobject1->real_escape_string(trim($_POST["UserName"]))); 
$FormPassword = $connectobject1->real_escape_string(trim($_POST["Password"]));
```

Please advise.

Comment: returning `[object][object]` does not mean that `ajax is unable to find the url`. It often means that it is returning a javascript object, which you are treating as a string when you do `alert(data);`. What is actually being returned from `'/sitename/s_logincheck.php'`? instead of `alert(data);` you could do a `console.log(data);` and view in your browser console what is being returned.

Comment: @sean thanks for the prompt response. The php script checks the database for user Id and password and returns error values. E.g. 200 if user does not exist, 0 if all is ok and then the success function redirects the user. What I find surprising is if these scripts worked fine when hosted locally then what could be the issue when I have just put them online.

Comment: I'm using plain echo "200"; at the moment.

Comment: My php script echoes an error code and the jquery displays the error message using if case. Do I need to return php response in a different way?

Comment: If something works locally, but not hosted, then there could be many reasons. Different php versions, included files were not uploaded, etc. For example, since you are using `->real_escape_string()`, I would assume you are using `mysql`, and not `mysqli` or `PDO` for you connection. It could be a database connection issue, or it could be that your host is telling you that `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: That could be one of the reasons I guess. I'll modify my code basis your input and check.